# Get multiple voice commands when launching an application

Tags: android, google-glass, voice-recognition, google-gdk

I'm trying to use my application to use voice command like "ok, glass" -> power_ball(home screen) -> game1(cardview) -> game2(cardview) ->

I tried lot of examples but I only manage to get into one screen(home screen)....From a home screen how can I call another cardviews using voice command

Here what I have tried so far

manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="info.androidhive.glassmenu.AboutActivity"
    android:label="@string/action_about" />
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.voice_trigger" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
    android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />



<activity
    android:name="info.androidhive.glassmenu.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/action_settings" />
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.voice_trigger" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
    android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
```

String.xml

```
      <!-- App start voice command -->
        <string name="start_command">do</string>
        <string name="start_prompt1">check1</string>
        <string name="start_prompt1">check2</string>
        <string name="start_prompt1">check3</string>
```

Please advice what must I do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look if [this](http://www.toptal.com/google-glass/building-your-first-glass-app-a-tutorial-for-aspiring-google-glass-developers) is useful for you

I was able to get a menu on my screen when saying ok glass in the app itself with the menu options that I've entered in my xml file.

be sure to add `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />` to your manifest. It's for using custom commands that glass hasn't accepted yet.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm using a XE22, The code you gave me is using old version of Google Glass..... so I cant get help

Comment: I'm using XE22 too. It worked perfectly fine for me. I didn't download the source code. I just started a fresh project and followed the tutorial so I would know exactly what was going on. So you shouldn't have any problems get that code working

Comment: I GET AN ERROR HERE private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);

    //Create a base listener for generic gestures
    gestureDetector.setBaseListener( new GestureDetector.BaseListener()

Comment: do you have the correct import?
should be `import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;`

Comment: @DaChavoh here I put it up on github for you. is working perfectly fine on my glass

https://github.com/MaikoHermans/TopFinderTut